# Joomla database migration

Tags: joomla, content-management-system, database-migration

I have a Joomla website but I have to admit that it is a mess. I've played with files I shouldn't have been playing with. Therefore I'd like to start over with a fresh installation. But I also don't want to lose my content.

Will it be enough to tell the new installation to use the old database? Or will that break it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have 2 option

1. Start a new installation on the same database and use a different
   PREFIX on tables (like  newjoo_)
2. make a bck folder, move existent folders and file in it, copy new
   file on the root of your FTP and use the OLD configuration.php file
   (so you have new files and old db)

*with the last solution you have a fresh installation but you dont have all old installed extension. you have to reinstall them (and you could have some conflict with existent data)

Comment: So as long as I'm using the same version it will work? Without any major problems?

Comment: Yes, with the same version work. But if you would be sure, try to remake the same server configuration. If you are on Windows machine use XAMPP. Make a backup of MySQL from your server and recover it on local. So you could do all the try before start.

Comment: Ok so recover the backup of the Joomla database with another name

Comment: Thank you. I think that's enough to get me going.

Comment: You're Wellcome. If you need some other help simply ask !